# FTPS PHP active PROT P

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ftps

I'm trying to do an upload of a file on a ftp space with ssl implied.

I connect it to upload the file it prompted the PROT P.

I looked around but I could not find anything on how to activate it.
you know help me?

I leave you my code and its verbose

```
$file = "prova_4u.csv";

$ftp_server="mio ftps";  
$ftp_user_name="mio user";
$ftp_user_pass="mia pass"; 
$path="/"; 
//$file =dirname(__FILE__)."/../application/archivosastras/".$localfile.".csv";
$remote_file = $path.$file; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
$fp = fopen($file,'r');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_server.$remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 990);

//SSL stuff curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_FTPS); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$ftp_user_name:$ftp_user_pass");   
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

//end SSL curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file)); 
$exec = curl_exec ($ch);

echo "\n\r".$exec."\n\r";

$error_no = curl_errno($ch); $error_msg = curl_error($ch);

echo "no - ".$error_no." - ".$error_msg."\n\r\n\r";

curl_close ($ch);

if ($error_no == 0) {   $error = 'File uploaded succesfully.'; } else {
    $error = 'File upload error.'; }

echo "\n\r".$error."\n\r";

fclose($fp);
```

Verbose Output

```
About to connect() to *********** port 990
*   Trying * * * * * * * *... * connected
* Connected to * * * * * * (* * * * * * * *) port 990
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: /CN=*****/C=IT/ST=Italy/L=Milan/O=***/OU=ICT/emailAddress=*****
*    start date: 2015-09-04 15:42:55 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-09-03 15:42:55 GMT
*    issuer: /CN=*****/C=IT/ST=Italy/L=Milan/O=****/OU=ICT/emailAddress=info@assistenzacasa.com
* SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway. < 220-Welcom to "******" FTP over TLS
service. < 220 Access by unauthorized users is prohibited and may be
prosecuted.
> USER **** < 331 Password required for ***
> PASS ****** < 230 Logged on
> PBSZ 0 < 200 PBSZ=0
> PWD < 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively < 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||50000|)
*   Trying *****... * connected
* Connecting to ****** (******) port 50000
> TYPE I < 200 Type set to I
> STOR prova_4u.csv < 521 PROT P required
* Failed FTP upload: 521
* Uploaded unaligned file size (0 out of 21 bytes)
* Connection #0 to host **** left intact


no - 25 - Failed FTP upload: 521

* Closing connection #0

File upload error.
```

Thanks

Comment: Next time please format your code so it makes some semblance of sense

Comment: What's the protocol part of `$ftp_server`? If it's `ftps://`, try changing it to `ftp://`.
(see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491790/php-curl-ftpes-w-explicit-tls-ssl)

Comment: I need a ssl implicit not explicit as in your link